# Dell Studio One - Integrated WebCam driver

Tags: webcam

I have a Dell Studio One with service tag: 1NBQWH1. The webcam on it doesn't work. I checked Device Manager, and under Imaging Devices, there's no webcam. There is an unknown device under Unknown Devices and an Unknown Device under USBs. I'm not sure if this is the webcam, but I'm assuming it is. I tried unninstalling these, but they come back when I scan again for hardware changes.

I'm finding it really hard to find a driver for this webcam, basically can't find it anywhere.

Do you know any other things I could try to get this working, or where I could find the driver?

Comment: I had no problem finding the drivers on the Dell website.